# How to find the limiting value for the sum when it is the upper range that is the limiter?

Tags: limits, summation

I want to find the minimum value of B, a function of S, as S-> infinity such that the inequality is always met.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{B(S)}\frac{(S-1)^{(n-1)}}{(S^n)}\ge \frac{1}{2}$

I am unsure about how to do that. Is there an analytic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This case is easy to handle:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{1 \le n \le L} \frac{(S - 1)^{n - 1}}{S^n}
    &= \frac{1}{S} \sum_{1 \le n \le L} \frac{(S - 1)^{n - 1}}{S^{n - 1}} \\
    &= \frac{1}{S}
         \sum_{0 \le k \le L - 1} \left(\frac{S - 1}{S}\right)^k \\
    &= \frac{1}{S}
         \frac{1 - ((S - 1) / S)^L}{1 - (S - 1) / S} \\
    &= \frac{1 - ((S - 1) / S)^L}{S}
\end{align*}$

Further simplification/work on extracting $B(S)$ from here is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, but that last result would imply that as S-> infinity 0>=1/2, would it not?